# Filtering return data from Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to search for specific data on a page.  I'm able to gather all the data from the page with:

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser') #html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('tr', {'class':"parent"})
```

It provides a number of lines that look like the following:

```
<tr class="parent" data-row='{"call":{"symbol":"BTCC  231215C7.00","class_symbol":"BTCC","root_symbol":"BTCC","underlying_symbol":"BTCC.B","expiry_date":"2023-12-15","strike_price":7,"instrument_type":0,"last_price":0.15,"volume":0,"bid_price":0.11,"ask_price":0.15,"bid_size":25,"ask_size":50,"net_change":0,"settlement_price":0,"open_interest":235,"is_option":1,"is_weekly":0,"last_close_price":0.15,"open_price":0,"high_price":0,"low_price":0,"nb_trades":0,"volatility":36.842},"put":{"symbol":"BTCC  231215P7.00","class_symbol":"BTCC","root_symbol":"BTCC","underlying_symbol":"BTCC.B","expiry_date":"2023-12-15","strike_price":7,"instrument_type":0,"last_price":2.52,"volume":0,"bid_price":2.08,"ask_price":2.32,"bid_size":25,"ask_size":25,"net_change":0,"settlement_price":0,"open_interest":0,"is_option":1,"is_weekly":0,"last_close_price":2.52,"open_price":0,"high_price":0,"low_price":0,"nb_trades":0,"volatility":71.286}}' id="BTCC-20231215-700" tabindex="0">
<td class="expiry_date" data-sort="2023-12-15">December 15, 2023</td>
<td class="call bid_price" data-sort="0.11">0.11</td>
<td class="call ask_price" data-sort="0.15">0.15</td>
<td class="call last_price" data-sort="0.15">0.15</td>
<td class="call net_change" data-sort="0">0</td>
<td class="call open_interest" data-sort="235">235</td>
<td class="call volume" data-sort="0">0</td>
<td class="strike_price" data-sort="7.0000">7.00</td>
<td class="put bid_price" data-sort="2.08">2.08</td>
<td class="put ask_price" data-sort="2.32">2.32</td>
<td class="put last_price" data-sort="2.52">2.52</td>
<td class="put net_change" data-sort="0">0</td>
<td class="put open_interest" data-sort="0">0</td>
<td class="put volume" data-sort="0">0</td>
</tr>

<tr class="parent" data-row='{"call":{"symbol":"BTCC  250117C5.00","class_symbol":"BTCC","root_symbol":"BTCC","underlying_symbol":"BTCC.B","expiry_date":"2025-01-17","strike_price":5,"instrument_type":0,"last_price":1.05,"volume":20,"bid_price":0.86,"ask_price":1.13,"bid_size":17,"ask_size":10,"net_change":0.17,"settlement_price":0,"open_interest":832,"is_option":1,"is_weekly":0,"last_close_price":0.88,"open_price":1.05,"high_price":1.06,"low_price":1.05,"nb_trades":3,"volatility":26.595},"put":{"symbol":"BTCC  250117P5.00","class_symbol":"BTCC","root_symbol":"BTCC","underlying_symbol":"BTCC.B","expiry_date":"2025-01-17","strike_price":5,"instrument_type":0,"last_price":1.49,"volume":0,"bid_price":1.13,"ask_price":1.38,"bid_size":10,"ask_size":17,"net_change":0,"settlement_price":0,"open_interest":678,"is_option":1,"is_weekly":0,"last_close_price":1.49,"open_price":0,"high_price":0,"low_price":0,"nb_trades":0,"volatility":62.77}}' id="BTCC-20250117-500" tabindex="0">
<td class="expiry_date" data-sort="2025-01-17">January 17, 2025</td>
<td class="call bid_price" data-sort="0.86">0.86</td>
<td class="call ask_price" data-sort="1.13">1.13</td>
<td class="call last_price" data-sort="1.05">1.05</td>
<td class="call net_change up" data-sort="0.17">0.17</td>
<td class="call open_interest" data-sort="832">832</td>
<td class="call volume" data-sort="20">20</td>
<td class="strike_price" data-sort="5.0000">5.00</td>
<td class="put bid_price" data-sort="1.13">1.13</td>
<td class="put ask_price" data-sort="1.38">1.38</td>
<td class="put last_price" data-sort="1.49">1.49</td>
<td class="put net_change" data-sort="0">0</td>
<td class="put open_interest" data-sort="678">678</td>
<td class="put volume" data-sort="0">0</td>
</tr>
```

However I'm unable to select the specific line.

I tried to get data from line so tried to narrow it down using the following code:

```
for result in results:
    name = result.find('tr', attrs={'symbol':"BTCC  250117C5.00"})
```

unfortunately it doesn't find the line I'm looking for :(

Once the line is selected I would like to retrieve the "bid_price" and "ask_price" for that specific symbol.

Comment: It's not helpful to say "unfortunately it doesn't find the line I'm looking for". Does it find nothing? all rows in the table? something else? Is your problem with the wrong tag? attribute? command syntax? Please edit your question to add more explanation what you think the issue is.

Comment: Also to make your example reproducible (MRE), please state the URL, if it's a publicly-available one.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the great answers.  Going beyond the first level of find in json was where I was struggling, and nice to see 3 different approaches!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `<tr>` that contains the symbol in `data-row=` attribute. Then select the correct cells:

```py
# html_doc contains the HTML snippet from the question
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

row = soup.select_one('tr[data-row*="BTCC  250117C5.00"]')
bid_price = row.select_one('.bid_price').text
ask_price = row.select_one('.ask_price').text

print(f'{bid_price=} {ask_price=}')
```

Prints:

```
bid_price='0.86' ask_price='1.13'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are searching for the `'tr'` tag with the attribute `'symbol'` inside the `'tr'` tags you've already found.

The info you're searching for (symbol, bid_price, ask_price, etc.) are all stored in the 'data-row' attribute of the 'tr' tag as a JSON string. So after you find all 'tr' tags with the class "parent", you need to get the value of the 'data-row' attribute and load it as a JSON object, then check if the symbol matches the symbol you are looking for. If it does, get the bid_price and ask_price from the JSON object.

Some boiler plate BeautifulSoup

```py
import json

url = "YOUR_URL_HERE"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('tr', {'class':"parent"})

target_symbol = "BTCC  250117C5.00"

for result in results:
    data_row = result.get('data-row')
    data = json.loads(data_row) # Load it as a JSON object

    if data['call']['symbol'] == target_symbol or data['put']['symbol'] == target_symbol:
        print(f"Symbol: {target_symbol}")
        print(f"Call Bid Price: {data['call']['bid_price']}")
        print(f"Call Ask Price: {data['call']['ask_price']}")
        print(f"Put Bid Price: {data['put']['bid_price']}")
        print(f"Put Ask Price: {data['put']['ask_price']}")
        break # Break the loop as the target symbol has been found
```

Script will print the bid price and ask price for both 'call' and 'put' options for the target symbol.